# Can't get the right resolution on Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: display-resolution

I use a TV screen through an HDMI lead as a monitor. I can't get it to work at 1920x1080 resolution any more. Previously I used to be able to just select this resolution in the Display Configuration in settings and it was fine. However since an update the Display Configuration box started giving 1024x768 as the only option (the TV is capable of a great many resolutions) the hover over gives the message "Using unsupported resolutions was possible in the Plasma X11 session, but they were never guaranteed to work and are not available in this Plasma Wayland session"

TBH I don't care whether I use Wayland or X11, I'd happily go back to X11 if it would let me get back to a usable resolution. However on the login screen the only option is "Plasma X11", there is nothing about Wayland listed there, so I AM logging into an X11 session as far as I can tell, so I don't understand why this is going on about Wayland. I'd even give up on Kubuntu entirely and switch to Gnome if that would work.
I've tried following instructions here: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-desktop/ to use xrandr to add the desired resolution but I get and error `xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default` I've Googled this error and can't find anything relevant to me (my nvidia drivers are installed and seem to be working, I tried unistalling and reinstalling them)

One thing that worked for me for a while was to set a line in my grub config file to `GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080`. This forced the grub menu to be the correct resolution and then when it booted up this was the only resolution available in Display manager (which was fine). However this workaround has now stopped working also. Running vdeinfo in grub now only lists 3 resolutions (not including 1920x1080). However `hwinfo --framebuffer` gives a very long list of resolutions that does include 1920x1080.

So I've got 3 possible workarounds, but none of them work! Please could someone tell me how to get at least one of these working? The workarounds are:

1. Get away from Wayland and back to X11 so that I can force 'unsupported' display resolutions.
2. Work out why xrandr is giving me the `Failed to get size of gamma for output default` error so I can add the right screen res.
3. Force the grub menu to be 1920x1080 as it seems that whatever res the grub menu is in is the only res that Wayland will then allow when it boots.

Comment: For reference, the output of `hwinfo --framebuffer` is:

`02: None 00.0: 11001 VESA Framebuffer                           
  [Created at bios.459]
  Unique ID: rdCR.RlQGS24uhn1
  Hardware Class: framebuffer
  Model: "NVIDIA GK208 Board - 21320014"
  Vendor: "NVIDIA Corporation"
  Device: "GK208 Board - 21320014"
  SubVendor: "NVIDIA"
  SubDevice: 
  Revision: "Chip Rev"
  Memory Size: 16 MB
  Memory Range: 0x01000000-0x01ffffff (rw)
`

Comment: (followed by a list of resolutions including several of 1920x1080)

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this in the end was the nuclear option of a complete wipe and fresh install. I tried installing Gnome over the top of Kubuntu (`sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`), but this didn't work, I still only got the one resolution option. So I then did a complete wipe and fresh install of Ubuntu (not Kubuntu) and this worked. In Display Manager Settings, the screen is correctly identified (Panasonic 32" TV) and it has the full list of possible resolutions, all of which work, including my desired 1920x1080 as well as 4k modes. I still don't know what was causing the original problem, but at least it's gone now!